# jqmodal not scrollable on a Mac with latest Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox, jqmodal

Any idea why a new Firefox (latest version) would not show scrollbars on a JQModal? Worked fine in every other browser:

Called like:

```
    $('#HTMLPreview').click(function(){

        var a=document.getElementById("txtStudentWriting").value;
        b=a.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "<p><p><p>");

        $.modal(b,{maxWidth:500,maxHeight:600,minHeight:500,closeHTML:'<a     href="#">Close</a>'});

        return false;
    });
```

include:
    <`script type="text/javascript" src="../include/js/jquery.simplemodal-1.3.5.min.js">

Comment: What is the latest version of Firefox that worked and the earliest version that fails it? Can you link to a testcase? I've seen another bug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=581240), which regressed in 3.6.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a toolbar installed in his browser. Those darned users!!!